# MySQL root always has access

Tags: mysql

## Background

I'm setting up a new server, and I'm attempting to secure the new MySQL installation.

- mysql  Ver 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.21.10.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

I'm logged in to Ubuntu as `root`.

I have run:

- `mysql_secure_installation`

... and flushed priveleges and rebooted.

It still does not ask me for a password. I have also tried to update this using:

- `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';`

## Question

When I attempt to login, I simply am automatically logged in if I type anything from:

- `mysql`
- `mysql -u root`
  ... etc

I assume it's not just "working out that I'm server root" and letting me in.

How do I configure this?

### Info

Running `select user,host from mysql.user;` gives:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Responded in the main question

Comment: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'`

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD('...')' at line 1

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('...') WHERE user='root'' at line 1

Comment: Ubuntu's "root" is not the same as MySQL's "root".  Do not confuse them.

Comment: See also `mysql_config_editor`.

Comment: I wasn't confusing ubuntu `root` with mysql `root`: 
"I assume it's not just "working out that I'm server root" and letting me in."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html)

> Important In MySQL 8.0, caching_sha2_password is the default
> authentication plugin rather than mysql_native_password. For
> information about the implications of this change for server operation
> and compatibility of the server with clients and connectors, see [caching_sha2_password as the Preferred Authentication Plugin.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password)

Test on my `MySQL 8.0.25` server

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.25    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyPassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
```

Or you could use :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyPassword';

mysql> exit;
Bye
root@ergesttstsrv:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@ergesttstsrv:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 23
Server version: 8.0.25 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Upvoted and marked as correct answer.